# Microsoft SQL how to construct the table from the rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cte with the list of the GUIDs like

WITH CTE AS
(
    Select GUID 
    FROM TableOne 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE

For each GUID I have a function that returns a table in the format

1. Row1
2. Row2
3. Row3

How I can combine the result in the new cte table like

Guid Row1 Row2 Row3?

Than

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation -- if you know the number of columns:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      Select GUID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GUID) as seqnum
      FROM TableOne
     )
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN GUID END) as GUID_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN GUID END) as GUID_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN GUID END) as GUID_3       
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon... My problem for now is how to use this function... It returns a table with 3 rows with only one column. The output of the resulted CTE should be GUID1, ROW1_forGUID1, ROW2_forGUID1, ROW3_forGUID1;  GUID2, ROW1_forGUID2, ROW2_forGUID2, ROW3_forGUID2 etc...